# Metropolis algorithm to solve a problem

Tags: pymc

I need to implement the metropolis algorithm to solve the example titled  *Cheating among students* [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter2_MorePyMC/Chapter2.ipynb). In summary the aim is to estimate the frequency of students cheating in an exam. The experiment is as follows:

Each student is asked to toss a coin. If the result is heads then student will answer honestly if he/she cheated. If the result is tails the student will toss a second coin and answer "yes, I cheated" if it lands heads and  "no, I didn't" if it lands tails.

The experiment involved $N=100$ trials and the interviewer got $X=35$ "yes" answers.

I need to find the frequency of cheating using a raw implementation of the metropolis algorithm. To that end I have identified the following variables in the experiment:

- $FC \sim Bernoulli(\theta=0.5)$. The probability distribution for the first coin.
- $SC \sim Bernoulli(\theta=0.5)$.  The probability distribution for the second coin.
- $TA \sim Bernoulli(\theta=P)$. The probability of a true answer. That is, a student honestly answering.

At this point is where I start to get lost. I think $P$ is the probability that I am interested in when using metropolis. However, it depends on the two other probabilities $FC$ and $SC$. Moreover, I would say it depends on a new random variable  $Z = FC \cdot TA + (1-FC)\cdot SC$ that depends on the two others.

My first question is: Am I right until this point in my reasoning?. If so, 
from what I understand, metropolis proposes a value at each iteration. The probability of this value is computed taking into account the distributions listed above. So, does that mean that at each point I have to evaluate the probability of the proposed value according to $Z$?.

Comment: The question is unclear as asked: if you want people to complete your code (a) this is unlikely to happen given the demand on the reader and (b) is not the purpose of this forum, since it sounds like a programming problem.

Comment: @Xi'an: I am not trying to get my program finished. I apologize if that was what you understood. I would say my problems are quite conceptual and hence probably relevant to this forum. I have a problem understanding how to link (conceptually) the probability of the new proposed value with the probability distribution of the experiment given all the variables influencing it.

Comment: I would then suggest you skip the code and describe the model and your problem in probabilistic terms so that readers do not have to read through the linked page.

Comment: @Xi'an, thanks a lot for your constructive help. I have rewritten the entire question.